# Remove path prefix of space separated paths

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Given a list of paths separated by a single space:

```
/home/me/src/test /home/me/src/vendor/a /home/me/src/vendor/b
```

I want to remove the prefix `/home/me/src/` so that the result is:

`test vendor/a vendor/b`

For a single path I would do: `${PATH#/home/me/src/}` but how do I apply it to this series?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `//` to replace all occurrences of substring. Replace it with null string to remove them.

```
$ path="/home/me/src/test /home/me/src/vendor/a /home/me/src/vendor/b"
$ echo ${path//\/home\/me\/src\/}
test vendor/a vendor/b
```

Reference: [${parameter/pattern/string} in Bash reference manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)

Answer (score 2):

Using [shell parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) <strike>doesn't seem to be the solution for this, since it would remove everything up to / from a given point</strike> is useful, as [nu11p01n73R's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37697607/1983854) reveals.

For clarity, I would use `sed` with the syntax `sed 's#pattern#replacement#g'`:

```
$ str="/home/me/src/test /home/me/src/vendor/a /home/me/src/vendor/b"
$ sed 's#/home/me/src/##g' <<< "$str"
test vendor/a vendor/b
```

Answer (score 0):

Like always a grep solution from my side :

```
echo 'your string' | grep -Po '^/([^ /]*/)+\K.+'
```

Please note that the above regex do this for any string like `/x/y/z/test ..`. But if you are interested only in replacing `/home/me/src/`, try the following :

```
echo 'your string' | grep -Po '^/home/me/src/\K.+' --color
```